Row Number Chronological Order (regardless of repeating values)
I am trying to assign a Row Number to my table based on its partition and chronological order. However, because some values repeat later down the track, ordering by the date results in the wrong ordering.
Below is an example of Row Numbers for both my bad execution (code below) and desired result:
My bad execution: ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PERSON_ID, CATEGORY ORDER BY DATE ASC)
Example Table:



PERSON_ID
DATE
CATEGORY
BAD
DESIRED




One
2004/03/11
A
1
1


One
2004/03/24
A
2
1


One
2004/04/16
A
3
1


One
2008/10/21
B
1
2


One
2008/11/17
B
2
2


One
2008/12/08
B
3
2


One
2012/08/28
C
1
3


One
2012/08/30
A
4
4


One
2016/06/07
A
5
4


One
2016/07/15
C
2
5


One
2016/07/18
C
3
5


One
2023/01/26
D
1
6


One
2023/01/28
D
2
6


One
2023/02/14
D
3
6



Thank you for your help in advance

Teradata or SQL Server? Please correct your tags.

And then try dense_rank

Hi Dale, I've updated my tag.
When I use Dense_Rank I get the same results. This is the code, I've used, feel free to correct it if done incorrectly.
DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY PERSON_ID, CATEGORY ORDER BY DATE ASC).

Create a DBFiddle if you want to make it easy for people to assist.

Your question was first taged as SQL Server, so I tried a solution for that RDBMS. Following query seems fine for your sample data:
WITH sub AS
(SELECT
  person_id, 
  yourdate,
  category,
  LAG(category) OVER (ORDER BY yourdate) AS lastCategory
FROM yourtable)
SELECT
  person_id, yourdate, category,
  SUM(CASE WHEN lastCategory IS NULL or category <> lastCategory THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
  OVER (ORDER BY yourdate) AS desired
FROM sub;

The idea is to use LAG that fetches the category in the previous row in order to check whether the category changed. If so, we will count up the column desired using a windowed sum.
The condition lastCategory IS NULL makes sure the first row will get 1 as desired, not 0 or NULL.
I renamed the column date to yourdate in my example to prevent issues because date is a key word.
This solution works for your sample data. You maybe need to change it for further use cases (dates should be sorted otherwise, different person_id's should be covered etc). It's up to you to think about that because I don't know your possible use cases.
I guess if other person_id's appear, your query should be:
WITH sub AS
(SELECT
  person_id, 
  yourdate,
  category,
  LAG(category) OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY yourdate) AS lastCategory
FROM yourtable)
SELECT
  person_id, yourdate, category,
  SUM(CASE WHEN lastCategory IS NULL or category <> lastCategory THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY yourdate) AS desired
FROM sub;

See this db<>fiddle
But as said, you need to properly describe your use cases if you need further assistance.
Since I don't use Teradata, I don't know if this query will work there, too. But I think this should at least point you in the right direction.

Thank you for the response.
True, I do need to clearly define my use case and will do so in future questions.
Your solution was close, though it did help get to the final solution. See below:
WITH SUB AS (
    SELECT
        PERSON_ID
        ,DATE
        ,CATEGORY
    
        ,CASE
            WHEN LAG(CATEGORY) OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON_ID ORDER BY DATE) IS NULL
            THEN 0
        
            WHEN LAG(CATEGORY) OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON_ID ORDER BY DATE) <> CATEGORY
            THEN 1
        
            ELSE 0
        END AS LAST_CATEGORY
    
    FROM MY_TABLE
)

SELECT
    PERSON_ID
    , DATE
    , CATEGORY
    , SUM(LAST_CATEGORY) OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON_ID ORDER BY DATE ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS DESIRED
  
FROM SUB
ORDER BY PERSON_ID, DATE;

